# camel processStrategy and move options not working together

Tags: file, apache-camel

I am trying move few files from location A to location B on same server based on the name and number of files present in that folder. To achieve this I am using processStrategy option and extended GenericFileDeleteProcessStrategy  to check for the batchsize. The files get moved to the destination but I also wanted to move the processed files to the .done folder and any failed files to the .failed location.

If I noticed that move, premove, moveFailed options are not working when used along with  processStrategy

below is the code snippet I have used.

Please let me know your suggestions. I need to have the files available in the backup.

```
public class CustomTestProcessStrategy extends GenericFileDeleteProcessStrategy<File>{
static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CustomTestProcessStrategy.class);
@Override
public boolean begin(GenericFileOperations<File> operations,
        GenericFileEndpoint<File> endpoint, Exchange exchange,
        GenericFile<File> file) throws Exception {

    boolean begin = super.begin(operations, endpoint, exchange, file);
    if(!begin){
        return false;
    }
    int batchSize = (int) exchange.getProperty("CamelBatchSize");

    if(batchSize != 2){
        logger.info("[OUT] CustomTestProcessStrategy Stopped. batch size is not met.");
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}
```

beans.xml

```
<bean id="testStrategy" class="com.camel.CustomTestProcessStrategy">
```

cameljob.properties

```
file.testmove.properties=?idempotent=true&processStrategy=#testStrategy&readLock=rename&readLockMinLength=0&initialDelay=10000&delay=5000&moveFailed=.failed&preMove=order&move=.done&scheduler=quartz2&scheduler.cron={{testmove.Schedule}}

folder.source=C:/readfiles/source
folder.destination =C:/readfiles/destination
```

camel-context.xml

```
<route id="FileTestMoveRoute">
        <from uri="file:{{folder.source}}{{file.testmove.properties}}"/>

        <bean ref="cifProcessor" method="startFinalProcess"/>

                <log message="*****************Moving file ${header.CamelFileName} to  the final desitnation folder *********" />   
                <choice>
                    <when>
                        <simple>${header.CamelFileName} regex '^.*(fileA).*(CSV|csv)'</simple>
                        <to uri="file:{{folder.destination}/FileA}"/>
                    </when>
                    <when>
                        <simple>${header.CamelFileName} regex '^.*(fileB).*(CSV|csv)'</simple>
                        <to uri="file:{{folder.destination}}/FileB"/>
                    </when>                     

                </choice>

                </when>                 
    </route>
```